# rust-crypto giving many unresolved import errors

Tags: rust, rust-crypto

I am not sure what I am missing. According to the latest Travis build this should be working fine. [#362](https://travis-ci.org/DaGenix/rust-crypto/builds/41376641) but i am getting many import errors.

Here is the snipped output of what i get

```
rust-crypto $ git pull
Already up-to-date.
rust-crypto $ rustc --version
rustc 0.13.0-nightly (336349c93 2014-11-17 20:37:19 +0000)
rust-crypto $ cargo --version
cargo 0.0.1-pre-nightly (56852db 2014-11-14 23:33:33 +0000)

$ make check
rustc -O  --dep-info src/rust-crypto/test.rs.d --test src/rust-crypto/test.rs -o rust-crypto-test

src/rust-crypto/aesni.rs:8:20: 8:30 error: unresolved import `aes::KeySize128`. There is no `KeySize128` in `aes`
src/rust-crypto/aesni.rs:8 use aes::{KeySize, KeySize128, KeySize192, KeySize256};
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
src/rust-crypto/aesni.rs:8:32: 8:42 error: unresolved import `aes::KeySize192`. There is no `KeySize192` in `aes`
src/rust-crypto/aesni.rs:8 use aes::{KeySize, KeySize128, KeySize192, KeySize256};

*snip*

src/rust-crypto/blockmodes.rs:814:71: 814:84 error: unresolved import `symmetriccipher::InvalidLength`. There is no `InvalidLength` in `symmetriccipher`
src/rust-crypto/blockmodes.rs:814     use symmetriccipher::{Encryptor, Decryptor, SymmetricCipherError, InvalidLength, InvalidPadding};
                                                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/rust-crypto/blockmodes.rs:814:86: 814:100 error: unresolved import `symmetriccipher::InvalidPadding`. There is no `InvalidPadding` in `symmetriccipher`
src/rust-crypto/blockmodes.rs:814     use symmetriccipher::{Encryptor, Decryptor, SymmetricCipherError, InvalidLength, InvalidPadding};
                                                                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 19 previous errors
make: *** [rust-crypto-test] Error 101
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very recent breaking change made enums [namespaced within their parent types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/18973).

They haven't yet merged [the pull request to fix that](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/pull/147) (Travis was showing the result of that PR)

Comment: shouldn't running `curl -s https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup.sh | sudo sh` have me up to the latest version, even if that is not the case, my version numbers are exactly the same as the ones in travis-ci, its a bit strange.

Comment: @Victory aha, the PR hasn't merged yet. https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/pull/147